# Error while rotating logs

Tags: rsyslog

I am two issue with the `/var/log/message` rotation. Below is the log-message configuration

```
# cat /etc/logrotate.d/logrotate-messages
/var/log/messages {
    daily
    rotate 7
    create
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    nomail
    noolddir
    postrotate
        /bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}
```

For some reason after the rotation the `/var/log/messages` file without any suffix not having messages but the last dated file having all messages `/var/log/messages-20200427`

```
-rw-------. 1 root root 6.8M Apr 12 03:36 /var/log/messages-20200412.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root  41M Apr 19 03:30 /var/log/messages-20200417.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root  43M Apr 26 03:13 /var/log/messages-20200425.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root    0 Apr 27 03:47 /var/log/messages
-rw-------. 1 root root 3.6G Apr 30 13:15 /var/log/messages-20200427
```

When I ran manually I see only one error on post rotate , like below.

```
#/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/logrotate-messages
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/logrotate-messages
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/messages  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/messages
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/messages, log->rotateCount is 7
Converted ' -%Y%m%d' -> '-%Y%m%d'
dateext suffix '-20200430'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding logs to compress failed
fscreate context set to system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
renaming /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages-20200430
creating new /var/log/messages mode = 0600 uid = 0 gid = 0
running postrotate script
syslogd: no process found
error: error running non-shared postrotate script for /var/log/messages of '/var/log/messages '
set default create context
```

The process which is writing to the file is

```
#fuser /var/log/messages-20200427
/var/log/messages-20200427: 41809
# ps -aef | grep 41809 | grep -v grep
root     41809     1  0 Apr24 ?        00:20:18 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

Not sure how to fix, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send SIGHUP to the wrong process:

```
/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
```

but

```
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

So you have to change that to

```
/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd
```

Comment: I included in the config, I will check for couple of days and let you know incase of any issues.